# Primitive data type immutability

Tags: javascript, immutability

I know, that all data types (primitives) in Js except objects are immutable.
So we can't do something:

```
let str = 'str';
str[0] = 't'; //error in strict mode
```

But we can do following:

```
let str = 'str';
str = null;
```

why this works and why primitives are immutable and objects are mutable?
I want to know what happened "under hood" (deep explaining).

Comment: You're assigning to the variable, not mutating the string value. If you want a non-assignable variable, use `const`, but this has nothing to do with the primitive-vs-object dichotomy.

Comment: `str = null` assigns a different value to `str` but does not mutate the original string value

Comment: Ok, but why primitives are immutable (in deep exlporer)?

Comment: @JohnDoe Because they represent mathematical values. You cannot change the value of 5 to mean something different than 5.